# How to display date in React.js using state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display date using React.js but for some reason it's not displaying anything.

I'm a beginner so I'm sorry if I'm asking a stupid question, but I can't figure out why it's not working. Can someone please help me? Thanks so much!

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    date: ""
  };

  getDate() {
    var date = { currentTime: new Date().toLocaleString() };

    this.setState({
      date: date
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="date">
        <p> ddd {this.state.date}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Where is your `render()` method? How do you call `getDate` function?

Comment: You have created a date object with currentTime, and are trying to display the `this.state.date` object

Comment: Without state: ```<span class="text-muted">&copy;{new Date().getFullYear()} All Rights Reserved.</span>```   Output: ©2020

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're trying to get the state of the date without explicitly setting it first. <strike>With that in mind call the `getDate()` method in something like, [ComponentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):</strike>

```
class App extends App.Component {
  ...
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDate();
  }
  ...
}
```

From there you should be able to retreive it in your render call:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div class="date">
      <p> ddd {this.state.date}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Update:**

[constructor()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) is probably more suitable for this situation as no external requests are called to retrieve said data:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    date: new Date().toLocaleString()
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks so much !   if i understood correctly componentdidmount is just calling the getdate function right ?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple way:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {date: new Date()}

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="date">
        <p> ddd {this.state.date.toLocaleDateString()}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Try doing:

```
var date = new Date();
this.setState({ date });
```

instead of

```
var date = {currentTime: (new Date()).toLocaleString()}
this.setState({date:date });
```

And check if the current date shows up.

Then check out how to alter the date field with some format.

Hope this helps you out

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking up [component lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

The state hasn't been set because you never call getDate(), so you're just getting an empty string.

```
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    date: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDate();
  }

  getDate = () => {
    var date = new Date().toDateString();
    this.setState({ date });
  };

  render() {
    const { date } = this.state;

    return <div>{date}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript codes by using `${}` like following:

```
<span className="xyz">
      {`${new Date().toLocaleString()}`}
</span>
```

Please note that you need to use the *Grave Accent character* (i.e.**`** ) around the *${}*.

Or if you want to convert a date-time string to local value, you can follow this solution:

```
<span className="xyz">
      {`${formData.updatedAt ? new Date(formData.updatedAt).toLocaleString() : ""}`}
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const tick = () => {
  const elem = (
    <div>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleString() } </h2>
    </div>
  );
  ReactDOM.render(elem, document.getElementById("root"));
};

setInterval(() => {
  tick();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can do it.

```
import React,{ useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";


export default function App() {
  const newDate = useRef(new Date());

  const [currentHours, setCurrentHours] = useState(newDate.current.getHours());
  const [currentMinutes, setCurrentMinutes] = useState(newDate.current.getMinutes());
  const [currentSeconds, setCurrentSeconds] = useState(newDate.current.getSeconds());
  setInterval(() => {
    newDate.current = new Date();
    setCurrentHours(newDate.current.getHours());
    setCurrentMinutes(newDate.current.getMinutes());
    setCurrentSeconds(newDate.current.getSeconds());
  }, 1000);
  const nowTime = `${currentHours} : ${currentMinutes} : ${currentSeconds}`;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(nowTime);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{nowTime}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: There's no need to keep three state variables. Just one, the date. And the hours/minutes/seconds can be derived from it.

Answer (score -1):

function ExpenseItems() {
const ExpenseDate = new Date()

return (

```
<div className="expense-item">
  <div>{ExpenseDate.toLocaleDateString()}</div>
  
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

);
}